# div element width not equalling 100%

Tags: css

I'm designing a site and am having a little trouble getting floated `<div>` elements to fit perfectly. I've removed a lot of the unnecessary code to illustrate my problem and have it in the fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/kWppv/

As you can see, the right-side edge isn't even despite my best efforts. If you read the .css, you can see what I've done to determine the width of the nav `<div>` and the container `<div>`.

```
#nav {
    width: calc(10% - 14px);
} /* 14px comes from two 2px border walls + 10px left-padding */

#container {
    width: calc(90% - 22px);
} /* 22px comes from one 2px border wall + 10px right- and left-padding */
```

The indent is six pixels wide, and this corresponds to nothing in my .css. (10% - 14px) + (90% - 22px) + 6px in borders + 30px in padding should equal a width of 100%, but it's only 94%. No matter what I change the width to (say I change the container `<div>` width to `calc(90% - 16px)` I still get the same six pixel gap.

Comment: That is because you don't calculate the width of the top and bottom div's. They also add a width because of the border. So they are `100% + 4px`

Comment: I suggest a quick fix, add `margin-right: -4px;` to the `#container`

Comment: @Bondye, son of a gun. So the width of the top and bottom `<div>` elements should be `width: calc(100% - 4px);` not `width: 100%;`?

Comment: If you're using `content-box` box sizing (currently default) then borders and padding both add to the width of your element, whereas with `border-box` sizing, these values are included in the width. Details here by Chris Coyier from CSS-Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use border-box

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

with this property width of element includes borders and paddings.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I'm curious to know if there was a way to set borders inside an element (ie. a 2px border extends 2px inside a `<div>` rather than outside as it is). This works, however.

Answer (score -1):

Try below CSS....

> ```
> #top {
>     width: calc(100% - 4px);
>
>     background-color: #CAEBFC;
>     display: block;
>     text-align: center;
>     padding-top: 10px;
>     padding-bottom: 10px;
>     float: left;
>     border: solid;
>     border-color: #1774A6;
>     border-width: 2px;
>     float: left;
> }
> #nav {
>     padding-top: 10px;
>     padding-bottom: 10px;
>     padding-left: 10px;
>     display: block;
>     width: calc(10% - 14px);
>     float: left;
>     background-color: #CAEBFC;
>     border: solid;
>     border-color: #1774A6;
>     border-top-width: 0px;
>     border-bottom-width: 0px;
>     border-left-width: 2px;
>     border-right-width: 2px;
>     min-height: 500px;
>     max-height: 500px;
> }
> #container {
>     padding-top: 10px;
>     padding-bottom: 10px;
>     padding-left: 10px;
>     padding-right: 10px;
>     background-color: #FFFFFF;
>     display: block;
>     float: right;
>     width: calc(90% - 22px);
>     border: solid;
>     border-color: #1774A6;
>     border-top-width: 0px;
>     border-bottom-width: 0px;
>     border-left-width: 0px;
>     border-right-width: 2px;
>     min-height: 500px;
>     max-height: 500px;
> }
> #bottom {
>     width: calc(100% - 30px);
>     padding-left: 10px;
>     background-color: #CAEBFC;
>     display: block;
>     text-align: center;
>     padding-top: 10px;
>     padding-bottom: 10px;
>     float: left;
>     border: solid;
>     border-color: #1774A6;
>     border-width: 2px;
>     margin-bottom: 50px;
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 540px;
> }
> ```

**Thank you,
Vishal Patel**